# Get the new size of panel and transfer to usercontrol after winform becomes fullscreen?

Tags: c#, panel

Is there any way to retrieve the updated size of panel after FormWindowState.Maximized? I can get the size of the panel but it's giving the original size of panel.

Thanks;

By the way this is the code for usercontrol

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this is the way i retrieve the panel size
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            this.Size = f.Size;
        }
    }
}
```

this is forms code, the panel has 4 activated anchors

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1 n = new UserControl1();
            panel1.Controls.Add(n);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you are currently using

Comment: Here's the code, my thoughts there is everytime i call the constructor it loads the designer.cs  from the form and gets the panel size there which is the original size of the form my problem is how can i get the updated size/latest size from the form

Comment: The code does not show how you are trying to read the updated size after the form is maximized.

Comment: How do i do that? i really need help, i have no idea how to get the updated. i only know is how to get the size but it is not the updated size which is from the use of constructor

Comment: @RhenzoPacho Take a look at my answer... and let us know if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is to resize the user control every time the parent Form is resized, you could use the `Resize` event of the `ParentForm`:

Main form:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ans
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var uc = new UserControl2();
            uc.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Controls.Add(uc);

            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
}
```

User control:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ans
{
    public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
            if (this.ParentForm != null)
            {
                this.Size = this.ParentForm.Size;
                this.ParentForm.Resize += ParentForm_Resize;
            }
        }

        private void ParentForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Size = ((Form)sender).Size;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh my it works! I'm very thankful sir!! Thanks for the idea  about the event from parentform now i can code peacefully

Answer (score 0):

If you want the UserControl you create dynamically at runtime to grow and shrink with the control that it is placed on, then set the Dock property of the UserControl to Fill at runtime:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl userControl = new MyUserControl();
    panel1.Controls.Add(userControl);
    userControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

Comment: thats what i used before, the problem is you can see the difference of the original usercontrol size and the dockstyle.fill. after you press the button the usercontroll will be added to the panel but it will show the original size of the usercontrol first before it fills the whole panel